# Grails dynamic finder where field name contains reserved words

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

So I have a grails domain class:

```
class Message
{
    Inbox inbox
    Boolean hasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient
    ...

    static belongsTo = [
        inbox:Inbox,
        ...
    ]

    static constraints = {
        hasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient(nullable:false)
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to use a dynamic finder as follows:

```
def messages = Message.findAllByInboxAndHasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient(
                    inbox, false, [order:'desc',sort:'dateCreated'])
```

This works fine running a unit test case in STS 2.6.0.M1 against grails 1.2.1;
Spinning up the web app, it fails because of the *By* in *hasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient* (I'm guessing it has confused the dynamic finder parsing when building up the query).

I can use a criteria builder which works in the app:

```
    def messages = Message.withCriteria {
        and {
            eq('inbox', inbox)
            eq('hasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient', false)
        }
        order('dateCreated', 'desc')
    }
```

But since `withCriteria` is not mocked, it doesn't immediately work in unit tests, so I could add the following to the unit test:

```
    Message.metaClass.static.withCriteria = { Closure c ->
        ...
    }
```

Is the criteria/unit test mocking the best/accepted approach? I don't feel completely comfortable with mocking this, as it sidesteps testing the criteria closure.

Ideally, I'd rather use the dynamic finder - is there a succinct way to make it work as is?
If there is no way around it, I suppose the field name *could* be changed (there is a reason why I don't want to do this, but this is irrelevant to the question)...

**UPDATE:**

Here's the stacktrace when I try to use `findAllByInboxAndHasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient()` inside the app - notice how it appears to get the last *By* and treat everything else between it and *findAll* as a property. i grazed on http://grails.org/OperatorNamesInDynamicMethods but it doesn't mention anything about *By* being verboten.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [byInboxAndHasBeenLogicallyDeleted] for class [class xxx.Message]
    at xxx.messages.yyyController$_closure3.doCall(xxx.messages.yyyController:53)
    at xxx.messages.yyyController$_closure3.doCall(xxx.messages.yyyController)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 2):

Testing the database querying is really an Integration test, not a unit test. Is your test in /test/unit or /test/integration ? - I'd expect the 'withCriteria' to be fully functional in the integration tests, but not in unit tests.

From the grails docs ( http://grails.org/doc/latest/ ), section 9.1:

> Unit testing are tests at the "unit"
>   level. In other words you are testing
>   individual methods or blocks of code
>   without considering for surrounding
>   infrastructure. In Grails you need to
>   be particularity aware of the
>   difference between unit and
>   integration tests because in unit
>   tests **Grails does not inject** any of
>   the dynamic methods present during
>   integration tests and at runtime.

Comment: It is a unit test (/test/unit). Unit testing against the dynamic finder will fail if I misspell Message.findAllByInboxAndHasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient(...) but not if I use the criteria and misspell eq('hasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient', false). Although I guess it will at integration test.

Comment: @rhu: in short, as Paul point out, you can't use Dynamic Finder in unit test, since Grails doesn't inject it at that time. To say it another way, findAllByConstraint is undefined in unit test.

Comment: @Hoàng Long: if I use mockDomain(Message, testData) from GrailsUnitTestCase in the test setup with some unit test data, then _some_ dynamic finders are injected - but not all; crucially findAllByInboxAndHasBeenLogicallyDeletedByRecipient() is and responds as expected, but the basic findAll() and withCriteria() aren't.

Comment: In the grails doc, hidden deep inside 9.1, it says: "Thankfully the mockDomain() method provides a lightweight implementation of the dynamic finders backed by a list of domain instances. Simply provide the test data as the second argument of the method and the mock finders will just work." - this is what I'm using in unit tests, and they work perfectly fine, but the same methods when injected in at the app must be implemented differently because they break badly, see my update in the question - sorry should've been clearer...